# MySQL OUTER JOIN to get separate row result from joint tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I tried this query

```
SELECT invoices.customer_id AS customer_id, invoices.id AS id, invoices.date AS date, due_date, bonus.date AS p_date, invoices.paid_date, total, bonus.amount AS p, invoices.paid, invoices.balance
FROM (
(
SELECT inv.customer_id AS customer_id, inv.id AS id, inv.order_id AS order_id, inv.date AS date, due_date, 
  GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT( DATE_FORMAT( p.date, '%d/%m/%Y' ) , ' (', p.amount, ')' ) SEPARATOR ', ' ) AS paid_date, 
  total, COALESCE( sum( p.amount ) , 0 ) AS paid, 
  ( total - COALESCE( sum( p.amount ) , 0 ) ) AS balance
FROM (
invoices inv
)
LEFT JOIN payments p ON p.invoice_id = inv.id
GROUP BY inv.id
)invoices
)
FULL OUTER JOIN bonus ON bonus.customer_id = invoices.customer_id
WHERE invoices.customer_id = '4'
GROUP BY invoices.order_id
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 10
```

And getting SQL syntax error but if I try LEFT/RIGHT instead of FULL OUTER JOIN and works with single roe result.

```
CUSTOMER_ID     ID  DATE    DUE_DATE    P_DATE  PAID_DATE   TOTAL   P   PAID    BALANCE
4   1   April, 24 2014 09:38:26+0000    April, 30 2014 00:00:00+0000    May, 10 2014 05:02:31+0000  28/04/2014 (10.00), 25/04/2014 (10.00), 25/04/2014 (150.00), 25/04/2014 (390.00)    680     100     560     120
```

[image: Getting this result]

Now the problem is I need P_DATE and P as separate row to display bonus. Can you help me to modify my query so that I can get bonus table record P_DATE and P as separate row and other as separate row.

[image: Desired result]

[SQLFIDDLE LINK](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/534eb/5)

Thank you

Comment: not quite understand it , mysql does not have full outer join it needs to be done done with left outer join UNION right outer join. Now for your problem could you please update the question and add the same output instead of the image ?

Comment: Thank you for your time. I have shared the SQLFIDDLE Link, You can see the real result and query on SQLFIDDLE and Desired result is image2.

Comment: the image that u shared could not be done with sql you are trying to shuffle the column values.

Comment: I need the P_DATE and P columns in new row. If this can be dome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
SELECT invoices.customer_id AS customer_id, invoices.id AS 
id, invoices.date AS DATE, due_date AS due_date,  invoices.paid_date AS paid_date, total AS total, invoices.paid AS paid, invoices.balance AS balance
FROM (
(SELECT inv.customer_id AS customer_id, inv.id AS id, inv.order_id AS order_id, inv.date AS DATE, due_date, 
  GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT( DATE_FORMAT( p.date, '%d/%m/%Y' ) , ' (', p.amount, ')' ) SEPARATOR ', ' ) AS paid_date, 
  total, COALESCE( SUM( p.amount ) , 0 ) AS paid, 
  ( total - COALESCE( SUM( p.amount ) , 0 ) ) AS balance
FROM (
invoices inv
)
RIGHT  JOIN payments p ON p.invoice_id = inv.id
GROUP BY inv.id
)invoices
)
RIGHT JOIN bonus ON bonus.customer_id = invoices.customer_id
WHERE invoices.customer_id = '4'
GROUP BY invoices.order_id
UNION 
SELECT '' AS customer_id, '' AS 
id, '' AS DATE, '' due_date, bonus.date AS paid_date, '' total, bonus.amount AS paid, '' balance
FROM (
(SELECT inv.customer_id AS customer_id, inv.id AS id, inv.order_id AS order_id, inv.date AS DATE, due_date, 
  GROUP_CONCAT( CONCAT( DATE_FORMAT( p.date, '%d/%m/%Y' ) , ' (', p.amount, ')' ) SEPARATOR ', ' ) AS paid_date, 
  total, COALESCE( SUM( p.amount ) , 0 ) AS paid, 
  ( total - COALESCE( SUM( p.amount ) , 0 ) ) AS balance
FROM (
invoices inv
)
RIGHT  JOIN payments p ON p.invoice_id = inv.id
GROUP BY inv.id
)invoices
)
RIGHT JOIN bonus ON bonus.customer_id = invoices.customer_id
WHERE invoices.customer_id = '4'
GROUP BY invoices.order_id
ORDER BY DATE DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Thank you, Yes this is the result I want, can you make this query compact or smaller? Thank you very much

Comment: @Saleem thank you. Great to hear the answer is useful. you can accept the answer so that it will be useful to others

Comment: I have accepted the answer but I have issue with the solution as the second line is not being included in the result http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7a6fa/2

Comment: @Saleem I have tried depending on on your problem statement. tell us in clear what exactly you want to achieve so that it will be clear for us to understand

Comment: You solution is good but Once I have second bonus it is not showing up. I need to display all the bonus in separate line and invoice data in separate line. Table schema us there. Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

I think it is impossible to do as you said (you should use two SQL statements)
Could you explain what is the target of this, maybe we can do it in other way.

Comment: I have shared the SQLFIDDLE Link, if you can guide to any other way to get the desired result (image), I will be thankful.